# How to create custom color filters by using CoreImage or Metal Performance Shaders?

Tags: ios, core-image, metalkit, metal-performance-shaders

I need to create color filters based on RGBA values. It's fine for me to either Core Image or Metal Performance Shaders. Core Image providing some default filters. But I need filters with RGBA color codes. Is it possible to create filters like that?

I tried this, but it's not expected result. I am expecting like Sepia Tone Filter with different colors. (Filter should apply to entire frame)

```
@interface CustomFilterByColor : CIFilter

@property(nonatomic, retain) CIImage *inputImage;

@end



#import "CustomFilterByColor.h"

@implementation CustomFilterByColor

-(CIColorKernel*)kernel
{
    static CIColorKernel *kernel = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        kernel = [CIColorKernel kernelWithString:
                  @"kernel vec4 CustomFilter1 ( __sample s ) \
                  \n { \n if ( s.r + s.g + s.b < 0.1 ) \n \
                  { return s.rgba = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.5); } \
                  \n else \n { return s.rgba; } \n }"];

    });

    return kernel;
}

-(CIImage*)outputImage
{
    return [[self kernel] applyWithExtent:_inputImage.extent arguments:@[_inputImage]];
}
```

It's working for me. Getting result image like this

[image]

But this is  not expected filter. I am expecting just color filters. like

[image]

Hope you got my point.

Comment: Show some sample codes pls

Comment: Thanks for answer. I just updated my questing with some code. Can you suggest me to apply normal color filters?

Comment: It seems like you got how to write a custom filter. So your question has been answered. There are a lot of knowledge on how to write a kernel, maybe it should be asked somewhere else.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by "just color filters". Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I have added sample pics to show difference. In first pic with custom filter, it's not showing as a color layer. second pic with color filter like CISopiaTone. I got color layer over image. I am expecting filter like second image.

Comment: Two thoughts. (1) In case there's a miscommunication happening, what do you mean by *"color layer"*. `CIKernels` work pixel-by-pixel on the entire image, and - usually - the output `CIImage` is used in it's entirety. (2) Assuming no errors in "processing" your kernel - which the code you've shown so far look good - is it possible that *something else* is happening? My first though is your kernel code is yielding "unexpected" results. (Where did you get this code? Why do you think it will apply a sepia tone?) But it's also possible that either your surrounding code (pre, post-) is the problem.

Comment: I think `return s.rgba = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.5);` is wrong. Shouldn't it be `return vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.5);`?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, working good for me. You can give any color you want. it will give output image with that color. You can change intensity of that color also.

```
   UIColor *color = [UIColor blueColor];
    /*
    [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f
                                     green:255.0f/255.0f
                                      blue:0.0f/255.0f
                                     alpha:0.4f];;*/

    CIColor *ciColor = [CIColor colorWithCGColor:color.CGColor];


    CIImage *outputImg = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorMonochrome" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, frameImage, @"inputIntensity", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.6], @"inputColor", ciColor, nil].outputImage;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the CIColorMonochrome filter in [Harbeth](https://github.com/yangKJ/Harbeth).

```
let filter = CIColorMonochrome(color: .random)
let dest = BoxxIO.init(element: originImage, filter: filter)
ImageView.image = try? dest.output()
```